Is there an ms exchange add in that can warn email users that they should consider bcc?
Users sometimes mistakenly send emails to external users and forget to use bcc. It's an easy mistake to make for less IT literate or very busy users. Is there a way of getting an "are you sure" when an email has a lot of eternal recipients?

Users sometimes mistakenly send emails to external users and forget to use bcc - Why exactly should they use BCC? What's the use case? Why do you see this as a problem?

Regarding to "How to add warning to mail to say mail send is outside the organisation?".  As a global admin, you can run this through Exchange online PowerShell. Ignore steps 1-3 if you already installed the Exchange Online PowerShell module and just connect (step 3). Run Windows PowerShell as an administrator and input the following. Ref: Connect-ExchangeOnline (ExchangePowerShell) | Microsoft Learn
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline #sign in with your admin account credentials.
Get-OrganizationConfig | fl MailTipsExternalRecipientsTipsEnabled
Set-OrganizationConfig -MailTipsExternalRecipientsTipsEnabled $true

Note: It may take up to 24 hours to take effect.
If my answer is helpful to you, please mark it as the answer so that other users can refer to it. Thank you for your support and understanding.

If you are using Exchange Online its not possible as the mail flow rules dont differentiate if the recipient is in the "to", "cc" or "bcc" field.

Recipient definition:

